# VBA macro word comment

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm new to VBA macros for word. I need to alter an exciting macro operating on comment in word. I need to add the comment reference to a string. What is call the comment reference is the string inside the square brackets, here SM4:

link to image http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13765664/wordcomment.png

How do i get the comment reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly clueless re Word coding, but this seems to do what you want:

```
Dim ocom As Comment
For Each ocom In ActiveDocument.Comments
    With ocom
        MsgBox .Author & vbCrLf & .Initial
        MsgBox .Range.Text
    End With
Next
```

Comment: This only displays name (author) and initials, not the reference.

Comment: I think what you're after is .Inital & .Index then.